# Nested Query on Entity Framework MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nested, entity

I have tried several things but it does not work. Basically, I want to add nested query on EF MVC3.

SQL Query:

> select * from Book where Book_PK in ( select Book_Ref from Library
>   where Library_Ref='18bd9526-f3e9-4d5b-86cd-ccfea64b6f7b' )
>
> Book_PK is primary key of Book
>   Book_ref is foreign key to Book
>
> Library_Ref is just attribute to filter the Book_ref

I have 2 tables: Book and Library which are connected through foreign key.

I only have one input, which is id, but this is not the primary key of Library.
I have tried:

```
`
School.Models.Entities.SchoolAll db = new Models.Entities.SchoolAll(); // db consists whole database

var temp = db.Books.Where(e => e.Book_PK.Contains(db.Libraries.Where(f => f.Library_Ref == id))).ToList();
// where id is one of the field of Library`
```

each Library entity may have one or may Book entity. So, the result of the query is supposed to be as list. I need to save this list into one variable. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Successfully done, converting below query:

> select * from Book where Book_PK in ( select Book_Ref from Library
>   where Library_Ref='18bd9526-f3e9-4d5b-86cd-ccfea64b6f7b' )

Into below entity framework:

> db.Books.Where(y => y.Libraries.Any(r => r.Library_Ref ==
>   id)).ToList()

Thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

you can use Singl method insetead Of Where, like below

```
var temp = db.Books.Single(e => e.Book_PK.Contains(db.Libraries.Where(f => f.Library_Ref == id)));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tried your solution. But it has 2 errors:
- string.Contains(string)' has some invalid arguments
- cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Schools.Models.Entities.Libraries>' to 'string'

What is wrong? the result can be multiple items/entities. Is Single is suitable?

Comment: in ef linq queries you can only use primitve types, like int, byte, string,... . and you can not use String.Contains method in it

Comment: Hmm.. do you have any other way to represent my above query? all involved attributes are in varchar.

Comment: yes, you can use SqlFunctions methods, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466169.aspx

Comment: I still don't get it, what the relation SQLFunction with my above query is.

Comment: you must use a method in SQLFunction Class instead of String.Contains, but i don't know exactly what function, please see above link yorself